# How can I upload .env file on ftp server through github action using SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@3.1.1

Tags: ftp, continuous-integration, environment-variables, continuous-deployment, github-actions

I am a noob to github actions. I was trying to push a laravel app to my server through github action. Here is the snippet is from my deploy.yml file.

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2

      - name: Create env file
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo APP_DEBUG=false >> .env
          echo DB_USERNAME=test_username >> .env
          echo DB_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.DEV_PASSWORD }} >> .env
        
      - name: List of files
        run: ls -a
          
     
      - name: FTP-Deploy-Action
        uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@3.1.1
        with:
          ftp-server: ${{ secrets.DEV_FTP_SERVER }}
          ftp-username: ${{ secrets.DEV_FTP_USERNAME }}
          ftp-password: ${{ secrets.DEV_FTP_PASSWORD }}
```

on console of github workflow

```
List output files                       0s
Run ls -a
.
..
.env     // created through "Create env file job"
.git
.github    // from github repo
README.md  // from github repo
index.php  // from github repo
...
```

when FTP-Deploy-Action starts running
it don't upload .env on ftp server.

I tried create .env file through `SpicyPizza/create-envfile` this action package to create .env file.

in action console I found

```
##[warning]Unexpected input(s) 'INPUT_ENVKEY_APP_DEBUG', 'INPUT_ENVKEY_SOME_KEY', 'INPUT_ENVKEY_SECRET_KEY', valid inputs are ['entryPoint', 'args', 'file_name']
```

It could not help to create the .env file.

Though after tried `touch` command to create .env I found that its not uploading in ftp-server

How can I to upload a newly created .env file through FTP ?

Answer (score 2):

SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action uses git ftp to upload the files. So you will need to add any untracked files to `.git-ftp-include`

[Per resource](https://github.com/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action#force-upload-specific-files)

> The .git-ftp-include file specifies intentionally untracked files to should upload.

[Here is an example run](https://github.com/meroware/ftp-workflow-example/actions/runs/238405486)

```
    name: FTP Test root upload
    on:
      push:
    jobs:
      ci:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - uses: actions/checkout@v2
          - name: Create env file
            run: |
              touch .env
              echo APP_DEBUG=false >> .env
              echo DB_USERNAME=test_username >> .env
              echo DB_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.DEV_PASSWORD }} >> .env
              echo "!.env" > .git-ftp-include # Add git untracked file
          - name: FTP-Deploy-Action
            uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@3.1.1
            with:
              ftp-server: ${{ secrets.DEV_FTP_SERVER }}
              ftp-username: ${{ secrets.DEV_FTP_USERNAME }}
              ftp-password: ${{ secrets.DEV_FTP_PASSWORD }}
```

**Notice** that we add `!.env`
The ! is basically telling git ftp to always upload this file. Without it won't work

Here is a sample log showing the upload. Notice how it shows including .env in the log

```
    Thu Sep  3 20:47:18 UTC 2020: Including .env for upload.
    Thu Sep  3 20:47:18 UTC 2020: Having files to sync.
    Thu Sep  3 20:47:18 UTC 2020: 9 files to sync:
    Thu Sep  3 20:47:18 UTC 2020: [1 of 9] Buffered for upload '.env'.
```