# How to update files on my website without using FTP client?

Tags: node.js, nginx, github, ftp, sftp

I uploaded static files on Nginx + NodeJS. The only way I know how to update the website is using an FTP application.

Is there some other way of uploading website assets?

Is there a package that allows commits in GitHub to automatically update my website in Nginx?

What are the best practices for updating websites? I tend to avoid CMS as much as possible as I'm only updating the website a few times only.

Comment: There are many ways of doing this, but it depends on your hosting provider.  Virtually anything is better than FTP, both in terms of security and compatibility, so you may want to find your hosting provider's documentation and look to see what options are available.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how you’re hosting your site. Some services provide their own tools for updating content within them. For example if we host our site in a docker deployment in aws ecs, then we would use aws commands to get that done.

If you’re fine with ftp, then you can create a GitHub action workflow to automatically update your site

You can take a look at the sample pipeline I provided as a response in this post for reference on how the workflow would work

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63731446/14167216